# Sign out fails for Gitlab integrated with Keycloak OIDC

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

When logged into gitlab using the oauth2 provider keycloak and trying to log out, Gitlab redirects to the sign_in page, but doesn't end out session on Keycloak, so we are logged in again.

These are the environment variables used in gitlab kubernetes deployment:

```
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_APP_ID
  value: <client-name>
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_APP_SECRET
  value: "<client-secret>"
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_CLIENT_AUTHORIZE_URL
  value: "https://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_CLIENT_END_SESSION_ENDPOINT
  value: "https://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/logout"
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_CLIENT_SITE
  value: "https://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/<realm-name>"
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_CLIENT_TOKEN_URL
  value: "https://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/token"
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_CLIENT_USER_INFO_URL
  value: "https://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_ID_PATH
  value: sub
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_NAME
  value: Keycloak
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_USER_EMAIL
  value: email
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_USER_NAME
  value: preferred_username
- name: OAUTH2_GENERIC_USER_UID
  value: sub

- name: OAUTH_ALLOW_SSO
  value: Keycloak
- name: OAUTH_AUTO_LINK_LDAP_USER
  value: "false"
- name: OAUTH_AUTO_LINK_SAML_USER
  value: "false"
- name: OAUTH_AUTO_SIGN_IN_WITH_PROVIDER
  value: Keycloak
- name: OAUTH_BLOCK_AUTO_CREATED_USERS
  value: "false"
- name: OAUTH_ENABLED
  value: "true"
- name: OAUTH_EXTERNAL_PROVIDERS
  value: Keycloak
```

I have tried a workaround mentioned here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/31203 , but no luck. Please help.

Note:

```
Gitlab version: 14.9.2
Keycloak version: 17
Kubernetes Version: 1.21.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be perfectly clear: the expectation is that you should be signed out of GitLabn, not necessarily keycloak altogether. This is happening correctly since you see the sign-in page after signing out. For example, if you sign into GitLab using Google and sign out of GitLab, you should only be signed out of GitLab, not Google.

The behavior you are observing is due to the fact that you have auto-login [(`auto_sign_in_with_provider`) enabled](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/omniauth.html#sign-in-with-a-provider-automatically), which automatically redirects users from the sign-in page to login again with keycloak (again) immediately after (successfully) signing out.

To avoid this problem, in the GitLab settings (under Admin -> Settings -> General -> Sign-in Restrictions) set the **After sign-out path** to be `/users/sign_in?auto_sign_in=false` or in other words `https://gitlab.example.com/users/sign_in?auto_sign_in=false`
Note the query string `?auto_sign_in=false` will prevent the auto-redirect to sign back into keycloak. You can also choose a different URL entirely.

See [sign-in information](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_in_restrictions.html#sign-in-information) and [sign in with provider automatically](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/omniauth.html#sign-in-with-a-provider-automatically) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the clear information, I have done the settings as you mentioned, now the signout is logging out of the gitlab, but after sign out  the problem here is when I open the gitlab URL in a new browser tab it logs in directly without being given option to choose whether regular login or Sign in with Keycloak

Comment: @rakeshkotian it sounds like you may want to disable the `auto_sign_in_with_provider` setting in that case.

Comment: I don't agree. For a sign-out to have any meaningful security effect, it must destroy the keycloak session as well. Otherwise, simply clinking keycloak sign in allows an adversary to assume the identity of the user without any credentials.

Comment: @RobertCutajar the sign out still occurs and destroys the keycloak session. The change just stops them from logging back in and creating a new session.

Comment: @sytech, in practical terms, the purpose of logging out is that if someone else comes to my computer after I sign out, they will not be able to use the service in my name unless they know my credentials. With keycloak signing you right back in, the sign-out is pointless. Zero security achieved with that. Security is hard. We must shift our mind to the reality that if it can be abused it will be abused badly. Not like your usual sw bugs.

Comment: Re: "For example, if you sign into GitLab using Google and sign out of GitLab, you should only be signed out of GitLab, not Google." You can stay signed in to google and other services. And yet, when a request comes from GitLab to sign-in with google, it should demand credentials. Simple as that.

Comment: @RobertCutajar that can also be configured. In the IDP I use (Okta) you can specify whether users should be required to login for every new login to a service or if they can use their active Okta login session without providing credentials. Similarly, MFA can be required alternatively or in addition for each service/login. I assume keycloak could be configured in a similar way.

Comment: @sytech , that sounds better. Would have to test that.